# Double switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I send two values of the form with the POST, for each value must assign different attributes. Is it possible to more simplify this code? Maybe in a different way?

```
$Prod_ID = $_POST['Prod_ID'];
$Merc_ID = $_POST['Merc_ID'];


 switch ($Prod_ID){
  case "29": Prod_ID = 2549720; 
    break;
  case "28": Prod_ID = 12458775; 
    break;
  case "3": Prod_ID = 233525; 
    break;
  case "14": Prod_ID = 884248; 
    break;
  case "1": Prod_ID = 5590367; 
    break;
  default:
    Prod_ID = 0;
    break;

  }

 switch($Merc_ID){
  case "29": Merc_ID = 4549724; 
    break;
  case "28": Merc_ID = 2496436;
    break;
  case "3": Merc_ID = 095355; 
    break;
  case "14": Merc_ID = 249321; 
    break;
  case "1": Merc_ID = 1240367; 
    break;
  default:
    Merc_ID = 0;
    break;

  }
```

Comment: couple(or 1) of arrays seem easier to me

Comment: BTW, you're missing `$` in your assignments.

Comment: Maybe more suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Zsw I think it's too minimal for CR.

Answer (score 2):

why not an array:

```
$prod_array=array(29=>2549720,28=>12458775,3 ...);

$new_prod=$prod_array[$Prod_ID];
```

Comment: *"why not an array:"* - wha.... no question mark? :p

Comment: @Fred-ii- its rhetorical , no question mark required.:*(&*(^*(^&%&$

Comment: ah, the *'ol one-two pohtaytoe poetahtoe* one-two punch I see. Gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values in an array and access by the index

```
$postProdId = 1;

$Prod_ID = array(
 29 => 2549720,
 28 => 12458775,
 3 => 233525,
 14 => 884248,
 1 => 5590367
);

echo $Prod_ID[$postProdId];
```

or you can use a data base.